# Getting rid of an instance of a class in Lua

Tags: oop, lua, lua-table, metatable

I am currently trying to do OOP in Lua. From what I've understood [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8392168/lua-metatable-class-destructor), the *instance* of a class and even the *class* ( the variable ) itself are a reference to the various bits and bobs the class holds, so if I have a method :destroy(), consisting of

```
function class:destroy()
  self = nil
end
```

when I call `instance:destroy()` the reference *instance* should be picked up by the *garbage collector* and practically, the instance *as in an object* is gone.

It won't throw up an error or slowly cause a memory leak, right?

EDIT : I thought that maybe I should include the following as well.

This is the method I use to create and instance

```
function class:new(obj)
  obj = obj or {}
  setmetatable(o,self)
  self.__index = self
  return o
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Generally, you shouldn't have to do anything to get rid of an instance or any other kind of table. The garbage collector automatically frees the memory of any table that isn't referenced by anything. If you really need to free some memory before a table goes out of scope, simply assign `nil` to its variable, and the garbage collector will do the rest.

Your `destroy` method doesn't have any effect, because `self` is just a parameter (which is a local variable). Assigning directly to it can't affect anything that the caller can see.

Comment: So instead of writing a fancy :destroy(), I should just directly do instance = nil ?

Comment: Yes, but even that's not necessary unless you know you're short on memory.

Comment: @Bogdan705: Even setting the instance variable to `nil` guarantees nothing. Other people might have a reference to that object, so the object will continue to exist. That's not to say that you *shouldn't* remove references to objects your local code no longer needs, but unless you are certain that nobody else *anywhere* has a reference to it, you shouldn't assume that no such references exist.